# Realm add object with update - ignore missing values

Tags: ios, swift, realm

**My main question is:** 

Is there a way of specifying a default value for a Realm model, which is only used when then the Model is being created from new, but is ignored when realm automatically updates the model from a `realm.add(thing, update: true)` call

**Here's some info for context...**

I have an importer script that pulls a load of data from an API and imports that into realm. Ignoring all the loops and nesting structure which isn't relavant, i basically have this:

```
let thing = SomeThing(value: [
    "id" : jsonData["id"].int!,
    "title" : jsonData["title"].string!,
    "system" : system
])

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(thing, update: true)
}
```

and my `SomeThing` model looks like this:

```
class SomeThing : Object {

    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var title = ""
    dynamic var system : System?

    dynamic var favourited = false

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }    
}
```

The `favourited` boolean is not provided by the API and is updated when the user favourites the object. However because the model default is false, when realm discovers the Thing already exists, it updates the values along with resetting the `favourited` back to `false`.

I know the obvious answer is too pull the object from realm and update it myself (if it exists) so i can control manually what get's updated (and this is what i will do if there's no better option) however there could be 100's or even 1000's of Things, so i'd rather try and avoid pulling the object out first just for this one issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in behaviours for Realm.create and Realm.add has been resolved as a bug, choosing the Realm.add behaviour. I've taken the following approach in the mean time, which compares all properties on an incoming object against the default values of a stored object and pulls them from the store if appropriate. There is a list of fields to ignore, too:

```
func hydrate<T: Object>(incoming: T, from realm: Realm, excluding excludedProperties: [String] = []) {
    #if DEBUG
    let propertyNames = incoming.objectSchema.properties.map { $0.name }
    excludedProperties.forEach { assert(propertyNames.contains($0), "Missing property \($0)")}
    #endif
    guard
        let key = T.primaryKey(),
        let identifier = incoming[key],
        let stored = realm.object(ofType: T.self, forPrimaryKey: identifier)
    else { return }
    let blankReference = T()
    incoming.objectSchema.properties
        .map { $0.name }
        .filter { !excludedProperties.contains($0) }
        .filter { incoming[$0] as AnyObject === blankReference[$0] as AnyObject }
        .forEach { incoming[$0] = stored[$0] }
}
```

Comment: Realm.add now has an update parameter that takes an enum of all / modified / error, where the modified case renders my fix unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

For those with the same situation, i found that `realm.create` with the update parameter set to `true` will do what you need.

Using the method in my question, realm will intersect the existing and new object and update any parameters that exist in both. Because the `favourited` parameter is created when you init the object, realm see's this as a change (which I already knew).

However, you can instead use `realm.create` and only pass in the values that you want to change. This essentially skips the intersecting of the new object (since it doesn't exist) and only inserts (or updates) the values you pass in.

So this:

```
let thing = Something(value: [...whatever...])
try! realm.write { 
   realm.add(thing, update:true)
}
```

becomes:

```
try! realm.write {
   let thing = realm.create(Something.self, value: [...whatever...], update: true)
}
```

> Note: the technical implementation of realm updates im sure is far
>   more complex than some object diffing or intersecting. The explanation
>   is provided only to help understand the issue and solution, not to
>   document the actual way it works

Comment: This no longer works since https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4926 was merged in Realm 3.0

Answer (score 0):

When you got the value from your server, do a loop to fetch the saved `SomeThing` that have the matched `id`, then update it's `title` and `system` along with the id, this way you can maintain the `favourited`, this is the only way i think, i dont think there's anyway to do what you mentioned.

Beside, you are creating new object and try to update it with the one that is already inside realm will cause error i suppose, not sure if now can? Since a realm object is not only contains those properties you declare but many more from its super class

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I use primary keys so when i tell realm to add the object, if the primary key exists it updates it instead. I was trying to avoid pulling the object out of the database first as that would (i imagine) slow things down. I found `realm.create` solves it though!